# Azure Resource Manager Query with multiple dynamic tag filters

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, cost-management, azure-monitor-workbooks

I'm trying to query the Azure Cost Management API and I want to be able to filter the results based off of 2 different types of resource tags but I am having trouble figuring out the format. I can get the single tag filter working, but I'm blanking on the format for multiple. Can anyone throw in their 2 cents?

Working single filter query:

```
{
    "type": "Usage",
    "timeframe": "{TimeFrame}",
    "dataset": {
        "granularity": "None",
        "filter": {
            "tags": {
                    "name": "Environment",
                    "operator": "In",
                    "values": [
                        {Environment}
                    ]
                }
        },
        "aggregation": {
            "totalCost": {
                "name": "PreTaxCost",
                "function": "Sum"
            }
        },
        "grouping": [
            {
                "type": "Dimension",
                "name": "{Aggregation}"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My attempt at adding more than one filter:

```
{
    "type": "Usage",
    "timeframe": "{TimeFrame}",
    "dataset": {
        "granularity": "None",
        "filter": {
            "tags": [
                {
                    "name": "Environment",
                    "operator": "In",
                    "values": [
                        {Environment}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Location",
                    "operator": "In",
                    "values": [
                        {Location}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "aggregation": {
            "totalCost": {
                "name": "PreTaxCost",
                "function": "Sum"
            }
        },
        "grouping": [
            {
                "type": "Dimension",
                "name": "{Aggregation}"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am very new to Azure so please don't roast me too hard lol.

Thank you to everyone who took a look at my question, much appreciated even if you don't have an answer for me.

Comment: what part of it isn't working?  not having access to the same data as you, even if we try to run it we won't get same the results you will.  having concrete examples of what you're getting, vs what you want  would be super helpful

Comment: Hi John, I'm specifically having issues with the "tags" section. Upon reading more I think I need to apply an "and" query filter to be able to add more than 1 "tags" attribute. link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage#queryfilter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue with the way my parameters were set causing a bad query. Here is the working code with multiple tag attributes for filtering:

```
{
"type": "Usage",
"timeframe": "{TimeFrame}",
"dataset": {
    "granularity": "None",
    "filter": {
        "and": [
            {
                "tags": {
                    "name": "Location",
                    "operator": "In",
                    "values": [{LocationTag}]
                }
            },
            {
                "tags": {
                    "name": "Environment",
                    "operator": "In",
                    "Values": [{EnvironmentTag}]
                }
            },
            {
                "tags": {
                    "name": "Integrated-System",
                    "operator": "In",
                    "Values": [{IntegratedSystemTag}]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "aggregation": {
        "totalCost": {
            "name": "PreTaxCost",
            "function": "Sum"
        }
    },
    "grouping": [
        {
            "type": "Dimension",
            "name": "{Aggregation}"
        }
    ]
}
```

}